# Apache Config Server Redirect only home page not others

Tags: apache, redirect

How to redirect the main page from
let's say  myapp.com to myapp2.com
but not redirect any traffic after the /
For example, myapp.com/aboutus.html should not redirect to myapp2.
But only myapp.com should redirect to myapp2.

```
    <VirtualHost  *:8080>
    ProxyRequests off
    ServerAdmin webhosting.group@myapp.com
    ServerName newitems.myapp.com

    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/myapp/web/apache2/data/htdocs/myapp/"



    #<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    #BalancerMember http://myapp2.com/ route=node1
    #BalancerMember http://myapp2.com/ route=node2
    #ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
    #</Proxy>



    #<Proxy balancer://mycluster8080>
    #BalancerMember http://myapp.com:8080/ route=node1
    #BalancerMember http://myapp.com:8080/ route=node2
    #ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
    #</Proxy>



    #ProxyPass /DripReport balancer://mycluster8080/DripReport
    #ProxyPassReverse /DripReport balancer://mycluster8080/DripReport



    #ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/
    #ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster/



    ErrorLog "logs/myapp-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/myapp-access_log" common
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That configuration is all in comments (lines that start with #), so nothing is being done, and it is normal.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule` is your friend here.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^/$" http://myapp2.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Here:

- `^`: starts with
- `/`: only / is to be matched
- `$`: ends with
- `L`: indicates it is the last rule to look at, do not process furter
- `R=301`: makes the redirection permanent, so client browsers will keep this redirect and not ask for it all the time.

So only `/` is allowed, anything else will not be redirected to your no2 domain.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html